# how to make remote calls using IIOP and omniORB

Tags: c++, visual-studio, corba, iiop

I have installed omniORB successfully on Windows Server 2012. I have two IDL files which I compiled using the `omniidl` compiler and now have a header file and source file for the two IDL files.

[image]

How do you go about writing a client that can connect remotely and make the fuction calls in C++? How does this process work?

I ordered the book `"Advanced CORBA Programming with C++"` which should be here soon, however, if anyone has experience with writing IIOP clients in C++ if you could explain how the connection is made and making a simple call. I am only making the client as the device already has the iiop server.

Comment: if you can choose I strongly suggest to use ICE instead - www.zeroc.com

Comment: @Slava This looks like a great alternative to IIOP!

Comment: @JonathanKittell Why not use the IDL to C++11 language mapping, that is much easier than the C++ one. ICE will not work because the server is using CORBA, so the client also has to use CORBA

Comment: We have a free CORBA programmers guide at www.remedy.nl that will give you some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would put this as a comment but I don't have enough rep.  If you are working with a cisco DCM (or any cisco product) I would recommend reaching out to cisco.

Just recently I have made a python implementation of CORBA (omniORBpy) with a cisco DCM.  I reached out to cisco and they gave me code that made the connection with some examples of method calls as well.

Alternatively omniORB does have some examples showing how to connect a client and server and pass information to each other.  See [the omniorb documentation.](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/omni42/omniORB.pdf) Under chapter 2 "The Basics" they have a few walk throughs.

Hopefully this helps in some way.